# How to understand the following formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Known
$$D:\{x^2+y^2\leqslant1\}$$
and $$\iint\limits_D\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ 
y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^1\mathrm{d}r\int\limits_{x^2+y^2 = 
r^2}\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ y\frac{\partial 
f}{\partial 
y}\right)\mathrm{d}s$$
I want to know what kind of Gauss formula this belongs to. I've looked up a lot of data, but I can't find it.

Comment: Lebesgue measure on $D$ is the product of the surface measure on the unit sphere and Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. So the identity follows by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: And by the way the notation $\iint\limits_D\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ 
y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^1\left(\int\limits_{x^2+y^2 = 
r^2}\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ y\frac{\partial 
f}{\partial 
y}\right)\mathrm{d}s\right) \mathrm{d}r$ would be better.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you. Can you explain without Lebesgue, because I haven't learned measure theory yet

Comment: @ mathcounterexamples.net Thank you for your answer. I'd like to know if this formula has a more general form. Thank you

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy  Or can any double integral be expressed like this?I hear people call this "Gauss formula".

Comment: @夜愿1998: $\int_{x^2+y^2 = r^2} F(x, y) ds = \int_0^{2 \pi} F(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi) r d\phi$, so what you have on the right-hand side is the integral computed using polar coordinates.

Comment: @Martin R Thank you, I know how to calculate the right side, but I don't know how the left side equals the right side, and I want to ask if this equation has a more general form, that is, can any double integral be expressed like this?

Comment: That is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables, applied to the parametrization $(x, y) = (r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)$ of the domain $D$. Here the determinant of the Jacobi matrix is $r$, so that $dx \, dy = r \, dr \, d\phi$

Comment: @Martin R So do you mean it gets the right one after two transformations? Can it get the right one more intuitively?

Answer (score 0):

An intuitional idea is:

You can tile $D$ by rectangles, left hand side,

Or by rings, right hand sides,

Or by circular sector, if you change the order of $s \ \& \ r$.

But the details is provided by what @KaviRamaMurthy referenced in comment.