# Did I do it right to calculate the derivative of this function at 0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\int_{0}^{x}\cos(t+\frac{1}{t})dt,&x\ne0\\
0,x=0
\end{cases}
$$
I made the following attempts
$$\int_{0}^{x}\cos(t+\frac{1}{t})dt=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{t^2-1}d\left(\sin(t+\frac{1}{t})\right)=$$
$$=\sin(t+\frac{1}{t})\frac{t^2}{t^2-1}\bigg|_{0}^{x}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{2t}{(t^2-1)^2}\sin(t+\frac{1}{t})dt$$
So$$f^{\prime}(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x+\frac{1}{x})\dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{2t}{(t^2-1)^2}\sin(t+\frac{1}{t})dt}{x}=$$
$$=0+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{(x^2-1)^2}\sin(x+\frac{1}{x})=0.$$
If yes,is there any other way to solve this problem?Thank you.

Comment: Well you can write the integrand as $\cos(t+(1/t))-\cos(1/t)+\cos(1/t)$ so the desired derivative is essentially limit of $(1/x)\int_0^x\cos(1/t)\,dt$

Comment: Your approach is also fine provided no typos.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Thank you!Your method is also good!Can you look at this equation for me, thank you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983488/how-to-understand-the-following-formula  I'm not very clear about other people's explanations

Comment: I can't comment on that question as I don't have much expertise on multi variable calculus.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh   It doesn't matter,Thank you again